# Does a road have to be on the surface?

Tags: timber-and-stone

I have dug a tunnel from inside my fort to the edge of the map. Will this work as a road connected to my town hall in order to attract immigrants, or does the road have to be on the surface?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I know can be built on a bridge in the air, so I assume so. You should leave it there in any case because the number of roads leading to the edge of the map increase the number of migrants and traders that come in 1.1

Comment: This would be cool to test, i've wanted to try and create and underground city. might try this when i do it.

Comment: I started to create an underground city, but then I realized that part of what attracts immigrants is the value of your buildings, and I don't think underground dwellings will have any value, as you can't smooth the walls the way you can in DF

Answer (score 1):

In order to attract Immigrants and Traders the road must be on the surface at the end of the map.

It can be underground all the way there, however the last part *must* be on the surface in order for it to work. I don't have any proof for that as I simply tried it myself.